# Default sampling rate Javelin 1?

Tags: sensors

I am trying to calculate quaternions using raw accelerometer and gyroscope data from the Javelin 1 device. What is the default sampling rate for the accelerometer and gyroscope in the Javelin 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampling rate depends on what version of firmware you have. For firmware version 4.0.0 and Android SDK version 1.0.0, the default sampling is 100Hz for the accelerometer and gyroscope. In later versions of firmware the sampling rate will be user controllable using he Javelin SDK.

You can find the documentation below: http://www.javelindevices.com/javelin_docs/com/javelindevices/javelinsdk/model/ISensorManager.html#setAcceleromGyroRate-int-

Comment: Firmware version 4.1.0  will enable sampling rate control from the SDK